# How to separate 2 images in react native

Tags: react-native

Here in my application I have added 2 images side by side in a scrollView but they are joined each other I want them to be saperated by spaces.

[here is the image of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5cHZ.png)

Here is the code:

```
<View style={{ height: 230, marginTop: 20, justifyContent:'space-around' }}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} >  
        <Image  source={require('../assets/images/restaurant.jpg')} />
        <Image  source={require('../assets/images/experiences.jpg')} />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add margin to each image and resize the images accordingly. If you dont want extra margin around every side of the images provide the first image marginRight and the second image marginLeft.